# Unable to call apex method using wire service, returning the result as [Object][Object]

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, wire

```
   
   <lightning:card>
    <lightning-button variant="brand"
    label="New Entry"
    title="Open Modal"
    onclick={openModal}
    class="slds-var-m-left_x-small"></lightning-button>
       
    <!-- modal start -->        
 <template if:true={bShowModal}>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" aria-modal="true" aria-describedby="modal-content-id-1" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
       <div class="slds-modal__container">
          <!-- modal header start -->
          <header class="slds-modal__header">
             <button class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse" title="Close" onclick={closeModal}>
                <lightning-icon icon-name="utility:close"
                   alternative-text="close"
                   variant="inverse"
                   size="small" ></lightning-icon>
                <span class="slds-assistive-text">Close</span>
             </button>
             <h2 id="modal-heading-02" class="slds-text-heading_medium slds-hyphenate">Quotation</h2>
          </header>
          <!-- modal body start -->
          <lightning-card>
          <p class="slds-var-p-horizontal_small">
 
 
            <lightning-input label="Date" name="datefld" type="date" value={fDate} onchange={handledChange} ></lightning-input>
            <lightning-input label="Quotation Name" name="enquiry" type="textarea" value={enq} onchange={handledChange} ></lightning-input>
  
            <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
               <lightning-input-field field-name="Project__c" onchange={projectChange}>
               </lightning-input-field>
               </lightning-record-edit-form>
        <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Price__c">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Unit__c"  onchange={unitChange} value ={unitVal}>
        </lightning-input-field>
        </lightning-record-edit-form>
    
     
   <lightning-input label="Unit Rate" name="rate" type="Double" value={rNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Additional cost" name="cost" type="Double" value={cNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Discount" name="dis" type="Double" value={dNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Agreement cost" name="agree" type="Double" value={aNumber} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input>
    <lightning-input label="Remarks" name = "remark" type="textarea" value={resultsum} onchange={handledChange}></lightning-input> 
   
     <lightning-button label="Save" variant="brand" onclick={handleClick}></lightning-button>
    
    
           </p>
          
           </lightning-card>
          <!-- modal footer start-->
        
       </div>
    </section>
 
 </template>
 <!-- modal end -->
   
    <div if:true={accList}>
        <lightning-datatable data={accList} columns={columns} key-field="Id" >
        </lightning-datatable>
      </div>
    <div if:true={error}>
        {error}
    </div>
  
   </lightning:card>
 
</template>
```

**JS**

```js
import { LightningElement , wire, track} from 'lwc';
import getAccountList from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.getAccountList';
import calculate2Numbers from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.calculate2Numbers';
import sentMail from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.sentMail';
import getUnit from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.getUnit';
import priceMail from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.priceMail';
import newPrice from '@salesforce/apex/PriceFetch.newPrice';
import { refreshApex } from '@salesforce/apex';
import { ShowToastEvent } from 'lightning/platformShowToastEvent';
export default class PriceScreen extends LightningElement {
    datefld;
    enquiry;
    projSelected;
    unitSelected;
    rate;
    cost;
    dis;
    agree;
    remark;
    recp;
    
    @track aNumber;
    @track unitVal;
    @track disName;
    @track finalCost;
    @track bShowModal = false;
       @track Name;
    @track columns = [
        {  
            label: "Name",  
            fieldName: "recordLink",
            type: "url",  
            typeAttributes: { label: { fieldName: "Name" },  target: "_self" }  
           },
             ];
 
     @track wiredDataResult = [];
    @track error;
    @track accList;
    @wire(getAccountList) wiredAccounts(result) {
        this.wiredDataResult = result;
        if (result.data) {
           var tempOppList = [];  
            for (var i = 0; i < result.data.length; i++) {  
                 let tempRecord = Object.assign({}, data[i]); //cloning object  
             tempRecord.Name = tempRecord.Name;
             tempRecord.recordLink = "/" + tempRecord.Id;  
             tempOppList.push(tempRecord);  
            }  
            console.log('hHIIII' + data)
            this.accList = tempOppList;
          this.error = undefined;
        } else if (result.error) {
            this.error = result.error;
          this.accList = [];
        }
      }
     
 
    handledChange(event){
      if(event.target.name==='datefld'){
 
            this.datefld = event.target.value;
        }
        else if(event.target.name==='enquiry'){
         this.enquiry = event.target.value;    
 
       }
        else if(event.target.name==='rate'){
        this.rate = event.target.value;    
          }
       else if(event.target.name==='cost'){
          this.cost = event.target.value;    
       }
       else if(event.target.name==='dis'){
        this.dis = event.target.value;    
        calculate2Numbers({ unitRate: this.rate,addtnlCost:this.cost,     discount:this.dis })
 
        .then(result => {
         this.aNumber = result;
 
           // this.error = undefined;
 
 
        })
 
 
        .catch(error => {
 
 
            this.aNumber = undefined;
 
 
            //this.error = error;
 
 
        });
 
 
    }
    else if(event.target.name==='agree'){
 
 
        console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value)
 
 
        this.agree = event.target.value;    
 
 
    }
    else if(event.target.name==='remark'){
 
 
        console.log('handle Change'+event.target.value)
 
 
        this.remark = event.target.value;    
 
 
    }
    }
 
   
    
    projectChange(event) {
       
        alert("PROJECT" + event.detail.value[0]);
       this.projSelected = event.detail.value[0];
 
       getUnit({ projId:this.projSelected })
 
       .then(result => {
 
        this.unitVal = result;
              })
 
       .catch(error => {
        this.unitVal = undefined;
 
 
       });
 
   
    }
    unitChange(event) {
        this.unitSelected = event.detail.value[0];
    }
 
   
 
   handleClick(event) {
    this.bShowModal = false;
    
  
    newPrice({ entryDate: this.datefld, enqName : this.enquiry, proj:this.projSelected, unit:this.unitSelected,
        unitRate:this.rate, addtnlCost:this.cost, discount:this.dis, agreeCost:this.agree,rem:this.remark })
      
 
   .then(result => {
    const evt = new ShowToastEvent({
        title: 'Saved succesfully',
        variant: 'success',
    });
    this.dispatchEvent(evt);
    console.log("Opps updated!" + result)
       return refreshApex(this.wiredDataResult); //HERE I AM CALLING REFRESHING THE DATATABLE, BUT ITS NOT GETTING REFRESHED
     
   })
 
   .catch(error => {
        this.error = error;
        alert("FAILURE" + error);
         //this.error = error;
   });
    }
 
 /* javaScipt functions start */ 
    openModal() {    
        // to open modal window set 'bShowModal' tarck value as true
        this.bShowModal = true;
    }
    closeModal() {    
        // to open modal window set 'bShowModal' tarck value as true
        this.bShowModal = false;
    }
  
}
```

**apex class**

```java
public with sharing class PriceFetch {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static List<Price__c> getAccountList() {
        System.debug('HII');
        return [SELECT Id,  Name
            FROM Price__c ];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static Double calculate2Numbers(Double unitRate,Double addtnlCost, Double discount){
     
        return ((unitRate+addtnlCost)-discount);
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = true)
    public static List<Unit__c> getUnit(Id projId) {
      
        return [SELECT Id,  Name FROM Unit__c where Project__c = :projId ];
    }

    @AuraEnabled(cacheable = false)
    public static Boolean newPrice(Date entryDate, String enqName, Id proj, Id unit, Id enqPrice, Double unitRate,Double addtnlCost, Double discount,Double agreeCost, String rem ){
     
       Price__c price = new Price__c();
       price.Date__c = entryDate;
       price.Name = enqName;
       price.Project__c = proj;
       price.Unit__c = unit;
       price.Enquirer__c= enqPrice;
       price.Unit_Rate__c = unitRate;
       price.Additional_cost__c = addtnlCost;
       price.Discount__c = discount;
       price.Agreement_cost__c = agreeCost;
       price.Remarks__c = rem;
       try {
        insert price;
        return true;
           
       } catch (Exception e) {
           throw new AuraHandledException('exceptionText' + e.getMessage());
         
       }
      
    }

    
 
}
```

In the js file, the `@wire` service calling the `getAccountList` method is returning the result as `[Object][Object]`, also the refresh apex is not working here due to this problem. I am calling the `refreshapex()` in `handleClick()` of js file.
Please help me!

Comment: Please edit your question and use the `{ }` button to format your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your apex class declares the `newPrice` method as such:

```java
public static Boolean newPrice(Date entryDate, String enqName, Id proj, Id unit, Id enqPrice, Double unitRate,Double addtnlCost, Double discount,Double agreeCost, String rem ){
  ...
}
```

First off, having this many params in an apex method is pretty counter to most design best practices. If there's really this much you potentially may pass in, probably better to pass it in as a state object. But I digress.

But the problem probably stems from how you're invoking this in your LWC:

```js
newPrice({ entryDate: this.datefld, enqName : this.enquiry, proj:this.projSelected, unit:this.unitSelected,
        unitRate:this.rate, addtnlCost:this.cost, discount:this.dis, agreeCost:this.agree,rem:this.remark })
.then...
```

By placing your 'params' in the curly brackets you've created a js object literal. Meaning you're essentially passing a single parameter of type object into your Apex method. Which should fail, as it doesn't resemble anything like a `Date` object like your method expects.

There's an example in the [LWC Recipes sample app](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes) for how to pass a composite input parameter into an Apex method. Essentially, you'll need to create a [wrapper](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/CustomWrapper.cls) class in Apex. The example looks like this:

```java
public with sharing class CustomWrapper {
    @TestVisible
    class InnerWrapper {
        @AuraEnabled
        public Integer someInnerInteger { get; set; }
        @AuraEnabled
        public String someInnerString { get; set; }
    }

    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer someInteger { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public String someString { get; set; }
    @AuraEnabled
    public List<InnerWrapper> someList { get; set; }
}
```

In your case, you'll create a structure like this to represent the inputs that you pass into `newPrice`. Maybe you call it `PriceWrapper`. You'd define these `@AuraEnabled` properties for each of the properties you'd want to pass to Apex. For instance:

```java
public with sharing class PriceWrapper{
@AuraEnabled
Date entryDate {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
String enqName {get;set;}
@AuraEnabled
Id proj {get;set;}
//...etc.
}
```

This will become the type that you use to define the method signature of your Apex method. In the recipes [example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/classes/ApexTypesController.cls), it looks like this:

```java
public with sharing class ApexTypesController {
    @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
    public static String checkApexTypes(CustomWrapper wrapper) {

    //...do something meaningful here with the input wrapper like
    Contact newContact = new Contact(LastName=wrapper.someString);
    //...etc
    }
}
```

So in your case, you'd substitute a single parameter of the type of your wrapper class for your however-many-parameters you have. Like this:

```java
@AuraEnabled(cacheable = false)
public static Boolean newPrice(PriceWrapper priceParam){

//...assign values from priceParam to a new Price__c object as before
Price__c newPrice = new Price__c();
newPrice.Date__c = priceParam.entryDate;
//...etc.
}
```

Then, in your JS file, you'll compose a JS object that has matching property names according to the wrapper class definition. For the recipes [example](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/master/force-app/main/default/lwc/apexImperativeMethodWithComplexParams/apexImperativeMethodWithComplexParams.js), we do that as follows:

```js
    handleButtonClick() {
        // Creating the object that represents the shape
        // of the Apex wrapper class.
        let parameterObject = {
            someString: this.stringValue,
            someInteger: this.numberValue,
            someList: []
        };
        // Populating a list
        for (let i = 0; i < this.listItemValue; i++) {
            parameterObject.someList.push({
                someInnerString: this.stringValue,
                someInnerInteger: this.numberValue
            });
        }

        // Calling the imperative Apex method with the JSON
        // object as parameter.
        checkApexTypes({ wrapper: parameterObject })
            .then((result) => {
                this.message = result;
                this.error = undefined;
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                this.message = undefined;
                this.error = error;
            });
    }
```

This part, you pretty much already have, as you're composing the object literal as you pass data directly into `newPrice`.

Note, there are a number of other items I'd probably advise you on in how you've created the JS in your component, and I've not tested this, but for the problem you describe, this would be the first thing I'd check/change to try to resolve this.